# how to update data in datagridview when updating the data using ef in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework

Sir when i want to update the data it would not update or refresh in datagridview

```
 private void load()
        {
            try
            {
                var query = from t in ffe.tbl_Partners.AsEnumerable().OrderByDescending(t => t.ID)
                            where t.Status== "UnProved"
                            select new
                            {
                                t.ID,
                                t.Partner_Name,
                                t.Advanced_Amount,
                                t.Date,
                                t.Tbl_Project.Project_Name,
                                t.Status
                            };
                dt = query.ToList().ToDataTable();

                tblPartnersBindingSource.DataSource = dt;
                advancedDataGridView1.DataSource = tblPartnersBindingSource;
            }
            catch { }
        }
```

this is the update code

```
  IEnumerable<tbl_Partners> tbl_s = tr.GetAll();

                    foreach (var item in tbl_s)
                    {
                        if (item.ID == id)
                        {
                            item.Status = "Aproved";
                            tr.Update(item);
                            load();
                        }
                    }
```

i want to accept changes when update the data

Answer (score 0):

You need to call

```
advancedDataGridView1.Update();
advancedDataGridView1.Refresh();
```

for refreshing the data grid inside the load method.

updated:

Try to Rebind your DatagridView to the source.

```
dvancedDataGridView1.DataSource = tblPartnersBindingSource;

// Update Data in tblPartnersBindingSource

dvancedDataGridView1.DataSource = null;
dvancedDataGridView1.DataSource = tblPartnersBindingSource;
```

Comment: SIr i have tried this but not work

Comment: @maherbabar put your complete code of the update

Comment: `Refresh()` is `Invalidate()` + `Update()`, both related to rendering the graphic interface, not related to the data

Comment: sir i have add the code above this will update the data in database but not in datagridview

Comment: @maherbabar data are binding properly?

Comment: Yeah data is binded properly it will be refresh when addad and deleted but not when edit

Comment: @maherbabar did you try my updated answer

Comment: yes but it would not work